# xPath expression is not finding text inside HTML

Tags: xpath

I have following XML:

```
<div> 
  <ul> 
    <li> 
      <a>
          Logout 1
     </a> 
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a>
         Logout 2
     </a> 
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a>
         Logout 3
     </a> 
    </li>  
    <li> 
       <a>
         Logout 4
     </a> 
    </li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

And I want to check if a `a` tag with the text `Logout 4`exists. I do this with the following expression:

`/div/ul/li/a[text() = 'Logout 4']`

Which doesnt seem to work, anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am testing my xPath on this site btw: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Comment: If you don't need exact comparison, you can also use contains(.,'Logout 4'), like this: /div/ul/li/a[contains(.,'Logout 4')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath didn't return any result because the inner text of the `a` element has leading and trailing spaces, which you can clear using [`normalize-space()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
/div/ul/li/a[normalize-space() = 'Logout 4']
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c7d02d9a66eb5d2136c3e9c66194cf2d)</kbd>**

or, if you really want to evaluate *only the first child text node* within `a` :

```
/div/ul/li/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'Logout 4']
```